# После foreach не работает while

Tags: php, wordpress, циклы

```
<?php foreach ( $otzyvy as $post ):
            
?>
        
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php while( have_rows('cf7-checkbox')): the_row(); ?>
    <button class="checkbox" value="<?php echo the_sub_field('checkbox')?> "><?php echo the_sub_field('checkbox')?><div class="img"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/build/img/checkbox_close_button.png"/></div></button>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

После foreach не срабатывает while, убираю foreach (в foreach свое действие, просто не стал загромождать вопрос) - все ок, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка

Comment: Вопрос бессмысленный. while никак не связан с foreach. почему не работает данный код - никто не знает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

проблема в том что вы называете переменную в цикле `foreach` как `$post`, и этим перезаписываете глобальную переменную `$post`, лучше использовать другое название для этой переменной например `$review_item`. если вам все же очень хочется использовать переменную с именем `$post` как значение в цикле foreach, то после цикла вы можете сбросить ее используя `wp_reset_postdata();`

```
<?php foreach ( $otzyvy as $post ):
            
?>
        
<?php
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<?php while( have_rows('cf7-checkbox')): the_row(); ?>
    <button class="checkbox" value="<?php echo the_sub_field('checkbox')?> "><?php echo the_sub_field('checkbox')?><div class="img"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/build/img/checkbox_close_button.png"/></div></button>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: "глобальную переменную $post". Я раньше не очень понимал, почему вордпресс вызывает у программистов омерзение и рвоту. А теперь понял. Вполне заслуженно